# Folderize favorites such as bookmarks in Firefox is needed for unix.stackexchange

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

Sometimes I use my favorites for learning purpose, but specifying favorites's category is hard.

Suppose unix.staxexchange is a firefox, and favorites of unix.stackexchange is bookmarks as in firefox. How can I create folder for bookmarks as in the firefox?

Comment: huh.... what? you can use `infavorites:mine [tag]`?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I only see : "vote activity newest views added" , You meang When i use you your suggesstion i can see a new tab to them?

Comment: i update my question so , question was changed,

Comment: Unfortunately there [is no RSS for search results](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/rss-feed-for-searches) so you can't subscribe using Firefox Live Bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Original Q: Searching within my favorites

@Braim's saying to do the following in the site's search boxes to get what you want. If you tell the search `infavorites:mine` or `infavorites:<SE user #>` followed by either text or a tag, `[bash]`, for example you'll get what you want.

See the example below which should help.

[image: ss1]

#### Updated Q: Favorites manager for stackexchange favorites?

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any method for "managing" favorites. You can bookmark them within your browser and manage them externally from the site. There might be a way to "export" them from the site and "import" them into your browser's bookmark manager as well.

This meta Q on stackexchange.com is asking for the very thing you're inquiring about. Titled: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/favorites-improvements-search-categorize-personal-tags-add-note-favorite-a).

Comment: i update my question so , question was changed,

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh - updated A.